# How to pass '--add-opens' JVM arguments to run ignite sink connector inside kafka kube connect

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, ignite

I want to use IgniteSinkConnector inside my kafka kube connect which using kafka version 3.4. I add ignite core and kafka ignite extension to my path and I can see that new sink connector was added and I can use. Problem is when I want to start it I got exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils
```

According to ignite documention I should add --add-opens JVM arguments but I don't know where when I just add jar to classpath kafka connect

Answer (score 0):

You can use environment variable `KAFKA_OPTS` to add arbitrary JVM flags, however, your error is more related to CLASSPATH not loading the JAR you added